# Store a custom object property in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I'd like to experiment with cellular automata using animation nodes.
For this I need to bind a property/value (e.g. boolean or float) to my objects in a grid.

Is there a way to directly bind values to the object? Like a programmatically updatable Object ID Key?

I'm looking for a method that's a bit more convenient than having a simple list of values that correspond to my object list and something that accepts Booleans (custom properties unfortunately dont).

Comment: Funnily enough Custom Properties can be Booleans if you set them via animation nodes.

Comment: Booleans can be achieved with an Int property with a min value of 0 and max value of 1